Electronic energy eigenstate
In the context of the hydrogen atom, the ground-state energy of the electron is $-13.6eV$. As the principal quantum number $n$ increases, the energy of the bound states approaches $0$.
$$
E = \frac{-13.6}{n^2}Z^2eV
$$
Question is: What is the highest possible electronic energy eigenstate for the hydrogen atom?
Is it: $0$ or $\infty$?
According to me, it should be zero but the correct answer to this question is given as infinity and I am not able to understand how it can be infinity.

The formula you give considers only bound states.

Above the bound state spectrum, there is a continuum of positive energy scattering states, their energies ranging from zero to infinity.

To be fair, calling an unbound proton+electron an atom is a bit misleading.

We don’t have the exact statement of the question but as you correct point out the highest energy for a bound state is $E=0$ and this corresponds to $n=\infty$.
If you are asked for the highest energy state the answer is expected to be the $n$ value of this state, and this would be $n=\infty$.  If you are asked for the energy of the highest energy state, this would be $0$.
